# Powershell: Add objects to an array of objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, scripting

I have this script where I want to add an object to an array called `$Target` in every foreach.

```cs
foreach ($Machine in $Machines)
{
  $TargetProperties = @{Name=$Machine}  
  $TargetObject = New-Object PSObject –Property $TargetProperties
  $Target= @()
  $Target =  $TargetObject
}
```

I know it is not working because `$Target =  $TargetObject` makes it equal to the same object.

How can I append to the array instead of replace?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To append to an array, just use the `+=` operator.

`$Target += $TargetObject`

Also, you need to declare `$Target = @()` before your loop because otherwise, it will empty the array every loop.

Comment: `+=` kills puppies.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old question but for future readers, the accepted answer is not ideal in **every scenario** especially when iterating over large sets of data within your loops.

The question is How to "Add objects to an array of objects". The title of this post vs the example problem given don't qualify for the same answer. Instead, I aim to address the problem demonstrated in the example.

While it's easy to use the append operator `+=` with an array, behind the scene, it's quite a wasteful process. The extent of how wasteful depends on the size of the object you're looping through.

The accepted answer starts with an initialized empty array `$Target = @()`. Then suggests looping through `$Machines` appending items to the empty array using `$Target += $TargetObject`. Behind the scene, PowerShell is measuring the size of `$Target` and the size of the item you're appending `$TargetObject`, adding the sizes together and creating a brand new array. It then copies/adds the contents from `$Target` to the new array followed by the object you're appending. This process occurs on every item in the loop. If there are 1000 items in `$Machines`, you will have created 1000 arrays by the end of the operation.

This all happens because plain old Arrays are a fixed size. By appending items to something that has a fixed size, we end up with this wasteful process. We can avoid this by not creating a new array at all. Instead, simply assign the array that `foreach` loops already create to a variable. See the following for an example.

```
$Target = foreach ($Machine in $Machines)
{
  # Stuff I want to be in $Target goes here
}
```

One of the other answers has the right idea but the example given is not correct. In order for anything to end up in the `$Target` variable, you have to make sure the data is being sent to the  [Success output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2). Not to be confused with data being written to the [Information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2#information-stream) when using something like `Write-Host`.

Here is a working example:

```
# Mock array for illustration purposes
$Machines = @( "Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3" ) 
    
$Target = foreach ( $Machine in $Machines )
{
    # This is being sent directly to the success output stream and therefore, into the $Target variable     
    @{ Name = $Machine } 
}
```

Your output should look like this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Machine1 |
| Name | Machine2 |
| Name | Machine3 |

If you're familiar with the Cmdlet `Foreach-Object`, below is the equivalent. You can start to see the similarities with my first example.

```
$Target = $Machines | ForEach-Object { @{ Name = $_ } }
```

These articles go over everything I just mentioned as well as the performance impacts:

- https://vexx32.github.io/2020/02/15/Building-Arrays-Collections/
- https://www.pipehow.tech/new-arraylist/

Comment: This is a really good, clear explanation, and is definitely the way to go in scripts that are regularly in use on production systems.

Comment: For your pipeline example, I think you want `%{ @{ Name = $_ } }`... Using `$_` instead of `$Machine` since the `$Machine` variable is never defined in your second example and would be null

Comment: @immobile2 That was an oversight on my part. You are correct, thank you for that. Fixed

Comment: If the goal was to create 2 arrays depending on what the object is, or in my case files from a Get-Child command, how would you add the items in that case? I am adding items to the array based on the month of the last write time. It will always be either this month or last month and sometimes ONLY this month. `$auditArray = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $backupPath*$auditExtension | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime)` then iterate through that array to add the items to 2 arrays. I suppose I could do 2 Get-Child commands, but this seems cleaner to me.

Comment: @mappingman I'm not sure I understand your desired outcome. If I wanted to create multiple variables that contain the objects based on the month found in the property LastWriteTime, I would do the following. Using your example, once I have all the objects from the Get-ChildItem command ($auditArray), I would create new variables filtering out only the objects I need. For example `$objectsInOct = $auditArray | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq 10}
$objectsInNov = $auditArray | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq 11}`

Answer (score 2):

Typically people do this without using the inefficient "+=" that makes a new copy of the array every time:

```
$Target = foreach ($Machine in $Machines)
{
  $TargetProperties = @{Name=$Machine}  
  $TargetObject = New-Object PSObject –Property $TargetProperties
}
```

Comment: This code needs some work, but it's actually pretty neat. As is, the foreach loop doesn't actually output anything if ran. As such, the `$Target = ` isn't actually catching anything. Removing the `$TargetObject = ` line will cause the foreach loop to spit a series of objects if ran. This, in turn, gets caught by the original `$Target = ` line and now you have a pretty Object Array. Neat.