# Add new set of values to ArrayList

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, arraylist

So I have the following ArrayList stored in `$var`:

```
ip_prefix   region         string   
0.0.0.0/24  GLOBAL         Something
0.0.0.0/24  GLOBAL         Something
0.0.0.0/24  GLOBAL         Something
0.0.0.0/24  GLOBAL         Something
```

I need to add a row to this however the following code returns an error:

```
$var.add("127.0.0.1/32", "GLOBAL", "something")
```

Error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "3".
At line:1 char:1
+ $awsips.add("127.0.0.1/32", "GLOBAL", "SOMETHING")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I'm sure it's something simple I have to adjust, however Google searches had me going around in circles.

Comment: Hi there. Have a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266013/add-objects-to-an-array-of-objects-in-powershell. Looks like you are adding to an array of objects. So you would need to set the properties of the new object when adding

Answer (score 4):

```
$var = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$var.Add(@{"ip_prefix" = "0.0.0.0/24"; "region" = "GLOBAL"; string = "Something"})
$var.Add(@{"ip_prefix" = "127.0.0.1/32"; "region" = "GLOBAL"; string = "SOMETHING"})

$var
$var | %{ Write-Output "$($_.ip_prefix), $($_.region), $($_.string)" }
```

Or:

```
$var = @()
$var += @{"ip_prefix" = "0.0.0.0/24"; "region" = "GLOBAL"; string = "Something"}
$var += @{"ip_prefix" = "127.0.0.1/32"; "region" = "GLOBAL"; string = "SOMETHING"}
```

Comment: `@{...}` -> `[PSCustomObject]@{...}`

Answer (score 3):

Should do the job

```
   $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
        ip_prefix = "0.0.0.0/24"                
        region = "GLOBAL"              
        string = "Something"           
    }    

$var+= $obj
```

Comment: This is the correct approach, but I'd use `PSObject` rather than `Object`, and pass the list of properties as a hashtable to `New-Object` rather than adding each property individually. On PowerShell v3 and newer the method of choice is using the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator directly on the property hashtable.

Comment: Good advice. I've amended the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Your output suggests that **your array list contains custom *objects*** with properties `ip_prefix`, `region`, and `string`.

You therefore **need to add a *single object*** with the desired property values to your array list.

By contrast, you attempted to add *3 indvividual elements* to the array list, which is not only conceptually wrong, but also fails syntactically, given that the [`.Add()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=vs.110).aspx) only accepts a *single* argument (technically, there is a method for adding multiple items, `.AddRange()`).

In PSv3+, **syntax `[pscustomobject]@{...}` constructs a custom object from a hashtable literal** with the definition order of the entries preserved.

```
$null = $var.Add(
  [pscustomobject] @{ ip_prefix="127.0.0.1/32"; region="GLOBAL"; string="something" }
)
```

Note how  **`$null = ...` is used to suppress the `.Add()` method's output** (the index at which the item was inserted).

[SQLAndOtherStuffGuy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45459491/45375) is on the right track, but **beware that `$var += ...` silently replaces the array list stored in `$var` with a regular PowerShell array (`[System.Object[]]`)**.